# Quirky starting

Tags: fuel-system, starter, pump

I'm the one who asked the question Monday about gas fuel pump situation. Well fast forward to today 3 days later. Car starts sometimes other times dead.not even a click. Last night started right up . this morning gave radio dash lights headlights turn key to start ...deadsville . nothing. Last.night started right up! What is going on here? Starter?

Answer (score 0):

Things I would check -

- Battery terminal connections.  Disconnect, clean and refit them making sure they are tight.
- Ignition switch is faulty.  This sounds like the most likely from the symptoms.  You may need to replace the electrical switch on the back of the mechanical ignition key.

If sometimes there are no dash lights, it won’t be the starter.

Check the battery connections then report back.

Comment: @Badluck Note that "battery connections" include **both ends** of **both battery cables**. The far end of one of the cables (usually the negative cable) may be difficult to access...but that difficult-to-access connection must be checked as well. The cables must all be in good condition, with each connection surface clean and free of corrosion, and each connection bolt tight.